# SQL join query output

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

**Table 1:**

```
userid(PK)               
name                 
age
```

**Table 2:**

```
jobid(PK)
jobname
```

**Table 3:**

```
userid(FK)
jobid(FK)
```

The above is an ERD. Say in table 1 I have 1 row.

> 1 - peter - 40

and in table 2 I have 2 rows:

> 1 - carpenter
>
> 2 - shepherd

3rd table contains the "intersection" of both, one to many relationship.

Since peter has 2 jobs, it would have rows as follows.

> 1 - 1
>
> 1 - 2

How would I merge the 2 rows into one? If I will, it will be displaying it as:

> Name: Peter
>
> Age: 40
>
> Occupation: Carpenter,Shepherd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.name
      ,t1.age
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(t2.jobname SEPARATOR ',')
FROM Table1 as t1
JOIN Table3 as t3 ON t3.userid = t1.id
JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t2.jobid = t3.jobid
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: Could you do me a favor, somehow translate this to CI query.

Comment: @user3205047 This is a different question and I believe you can do it yourself: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html

Comment: Thnx, i just converted it a while ago. I was just asking for reassurance if my syntax is wrong so i would notice right away. Still though, thanks! for your answer

Comment: PLEASE LOOK AT QUESTION AGAIN, i edited it and asked for deletion for ERD using where_in clause.

Comment: @user3205047 Please do not edit your question into another one, I have rolled it back. This is not the right way to use SO. If you have another question, post it separately.